# How can I stop OverflowException being thrown on integer division?

Tags: c#, .net, math, overflowexception

I am getting **OverflowException**'s thrown at me when I don't want them (or so I think). I am performing some odd calculations where I expect the values to overflow, discarding overflowed bits. It seems I can't get this to work properly though. Basically this is one pair of i and j which happens as I iterate over huge sets (int.MinValue to int.MaxValue).

```
// i and j are ints
// i is -2147483648
// j is -1
var x = i / j;

// I also tried using unchecked keyword, but it doesn't help    
var x = unchecked(i / j);
```

Update:

The expected mathematic value of -2147483648 / -1 is 2147483648. However, this certain code doesn't really attempt to find the number. This is part of a series of bit manipulation things gone a bit hard to understand. To be honest, I don't even know myself what the intention was because I didn't really document the method, and all it took was one day away from it to raise serious WTF-bubbles over my head. All I know it works as intended with special code designed to handle the case.

About the expected value:

Since int can only hold 2147483647 at it's max, I expect to discard the overflow yielding value 0.

If I've learned anything about this at all, it's probably the importance of documentation for obscure methods.

Comment: I do hope you have a try/catch block around this in the real code?

Comment: No, I don't. However, I do make sure I don't divide with zero.

Comment: Regarding your edit: Would you expect `int.MaxValue + 1`, which also equals 2147483648, to overflow to zero?

Comment: No, I wouldn't. Anyhow, I suppose I already solved the issue (though I don't think it's neat to have a check for it). Thanks for your help. In case anyone comes up with a "clean" solution for the expected behaviour, feel free to post it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is the *only* case in which you'll get this exception. It's the only division within the `Int32` range which can overflow. (There's division by zero of course, but that's a different exception.)

So if you want to avoid `OverflowException` you *only* need to deal with this case. What do you want it to do? Write a method which spots this *exact* case, and otherwise does normal division.

Note: this is also why you shouldn't try to reverse a comparison by just negating the result. If you want to sort something in descending order instead of ascending, then instead of using `-Compare(x, y)` use `Compare(y, x)`. The negation *doesn't* give overflow for `int.MinValue` (unless you're in a checked context) - it just silently returns `int.MinValue`.

Comment: From your post I understand, that negating int.MaxValue returns int.MinValue, instead of overflowing, but negating int.MaxValue returns int.MinValue + 1 as it should (cause range is between 2147483647 and -2147483648). Also, negating int.MinValue is a place where it should overflow, but than - c# happily returns int.MinValue again (or throws inside checked{}). Have I misunderstood your point, or is it a typo?

Comment: Typo - that MaxValue should have been MinValue.

Answer (score 3):

Twos complement means that integers will range from 2^32 - 1 to -2^32, so -2147483648 / -1  is returning a number which can't be represented by an `int`.

You could try putting it into a `long`. There's no reason to use a `var` in this situation.

Comment: Actually, doing something like this: x = i / j;, where x is long won't help, whole operation must be performed on long, so x = (long)i / j; will work, and because result will be long, here var can be used (although I personally don't like using var in such context, but that's whole different story.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP knows this. His problem is that unchecked doesn't work the way it should. The only exception that unchecked should allow is div by 0. Whether x is int or var does not matter in this example.

Answer (score 0):

You can workaround this with a bit of casting to/from `Int64`:

```
var x = (int)((long)i / j);
```

Comment: Doesn't work. `x` ends up with `-2147483648`, and the right answer is `2147483648`. As **Pike65** correctly pointed out, this number can't be represented in a signed 32 bit integer. The only way to solve this problem is by using some other type, like `long`.

Comment: @jpbochi: The OP is expecting it to overflow, and wants it to do so without an exception being thrown. The "overflowed" `Int32` equivalent of 2147483648 is -2147483648.

Comment: @jpbochi, Try this: `var x = unchecked(int.MaxValue + 1);`

Answer (score 0):

You do this. Why would you use `var` here? It loses the ability to show you the type of arithmetic result all for saving 1 character...

```
long x = (long)i / j;
```

If you want saturation, you can:

```
int x = (int)Math.Min((long)i / j, int.MaxValue);
```

Comment: The question suggests that the OP expects the result to be an "overflowed" `int`, not a `long`: "I expect the values to overflow, discarding overflowed bits".

Comment: To be honest, having var or int is irrelevant because the evaulation of the types will cause var to take the type of int. I chose var in case I would have to write similar code for long, where I wouldn't have to refactor alot if I used var.