# Floored integer division

Tags: c#, .net, math, integer-arithmetic

Is there an easy, efficient and correct (i.e. not involving conversions to/from double) way to do **floored integer division** (like e.g. [Python offers](http://python-history.blogspot.jp/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html)) in C#.

In other words, an efficient version of the following, that does not suffer from long/double conversion losses.

```
(long)(Math.Floor((double) a / b))
```

or does one have to implement it oneself, like e.g.

```
static long FlooredIntDiv(long a, long b)
{
    if (a < 0)
    {
        if (b > 0)
            return (a - b + 1) / b;
        // if (a == long.MinValue && b == -1) // see *) below
        //    throw new OverflowException();
    }
    else if (a > 0)
    {
        if (b < 0)
            return (a - b - 1) / b;
    }
    return a / b;
}
```

<strike>*) Although the C# 4 spec of the Division operator [leaves it open](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26595091/709537) whether `OverflowException` is raised inside `unchecked`, in reality it does throw (on my system) and the [Visual Studio .NET 2003 version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691373.aspx) even mandated it throw:</strike>

> If the left operand is the smallest representable int or long value and the right operand is –1, [..] System.OverflowException is always thrown in this situation, regardless of whether the operation occurs in a checked or an unchecked context.

**Edit**

The crossed out statements about `checked` and `unchecked` are all nice and well, but **`checked` is in fact only a [compile time concept](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28080262/709537)**, so whether my function should wrap around or throw is up to me anyway, regardless of whether code calling the function is inside `checked` or not.

Comment: You mean, an alternative to just passing the result into `Math.Floor`?

Comment: Integer division is already doing that, not literally calling `Math.Floor`, but result is the same, it cuts off whole decimal part. `Math.Floor` is redundant in this case.

Comment: @maremp: only for positive results. See the OP's table for examples of "floor" negative results that are different from the C# `/` operator implementation.

Comment: Oh yeah @PeterDuniho, I forgot about that...

Comment: Not a solution, but I believe your code might fail in some corner cases. `var a = long.MinValue; var b = -1L;` OR `var a = long.MaxValue; var b = -1L;`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
if (((a < 0) ^ (b < 0)) && (a % b != 0))
{
   return (a/b - 1);
}
else
{
   return (a/b);
}
```

**Edit** (after some discussions in comments below):

Without using if-else, I would go like this:

```
return (a/b - Convert.ToInt32(((a < 0) ^ (b < 0)) && (a % b != 0)));
```

Note: `Convert.ToIn32(bool value)` also needs a jump, see [implemention](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,d75d8ee9b3529289) of the method:

```
return value? Boolean.True: Boolean.False;
```

Theoretically, it is not possible to calculate the division for `a = long.MinValue` and `b = -1L`, since the expected result is `a/b = abs(long.MinValue) = long.MaxValue + 1 > long.MaxValue`. (Range of long is `–9,223,372,036,854,775,808` to `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`.)

Comment: PS: ^ is xor operator

Comment: Thanks L16H7. When implementing my `FlooredIntDiv` above, I started off similar to your solution, which is as efficient, and I believe, as correct as mine (I haven't thought through whether your solution catches all the `0` corner cases), but I went the `if/else` route because I think it's easier to read. So it is equivalent to my sample implementation, but neither easier nor more efficient.

Comment: Normally, an "efficient" formula should not use any "if" statements and the like. It should based purely on low-level arithmetic operators.

Comment: If I have to remove `if-else`, I would go like this: `{ return (a/b - Convert.ToInt32(((a < 0) ^ (b < 0)) && (a % b != 0))); }`. I'm using the fact that true = 1 and false = 0 when bool is converted to int.

Comment: @L16H7 FYI: Your solution throws an `OverflowException` for `a = long.MinValue` and `b = -1L`. I tested it because publicgk (incorrectly) suggested my solution *might* fail for those numbers.

Comment: It should fail since for `a = long.MinValue` and `b = -1L`, the expected result is `a/b = abs(long.MinValue) = long.MaxValue + 1`. Range of long is `–9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807`. Does your program give the correct result? @EugeneBeresovsky

Comment: Put a limit on the input. :) Case closed. @EugeneBeresovsky

Comment: @L16H7 Re: correctness. I investigated a bit more, removed my previously uninformed comments and updated the question instead.

Comment: So what do you want now? @EugeneBeresovsky.

Comment: @L16H7 I was just trying to say (as my question now clarifies) - neither your nor my implementation is "incorrect" - so sorry for upsetting the applecart. I'm however still interested in any easy and efficient solution, if there is one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69363/discussion-between-l16h7-and-eugene-beresovsky).

Comment: What was the outcome? I'm interested too. The link to the chat does not work.

Comment: There may be no if-elses, but wouldn't using `&&` cause branching due to short-circuit logic? (branching when the left hand side is false) Using `&` would prevent short circuiting.

Answer (score 0):

If both arguments a and b are long (or any other integer type)

```
long c = a/b;
```

is giving a floor integer division in C# just like in Python. Nothing to convert to anything. It is even using a proper integer operation on the processor level.

All operations in C# are executed based on their types.

Comment: Integer division rounds towards zero, so if a or b are negative the result will be rounded up instead of down.