# How can I check if I'm in a checked context?

Tags: c#, .net, math

How can I find out, using C# code, if I'm in a `checked` context or not, without causing/catching an `OverflowException`, with the performance penalty that incurs?

Comment: Is there a practical reason for needing to know? If you need to be in one other the other context, that's what the `checked` and `unchecked` operators are for. If you don't need to be in one or the other, why would you care to know?

Comment: I am afraid causing/catching `OverflowException` is by far the easiest way,  if not the only way.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot (Say) I want to [implement an arithmetic operation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28059655/709537) that only throws on arithmetic overflows if inside `checked`.

Comment: @EugeneBeresovsky I wasn't aware of the undefined corner case called out from the linked answer, intestesting. For what's it's worth, the undefined case remains in the C# 5.0 spec as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only difference between a block that is `checked` vs `unchecked` are the IL instructions generated by the compiler for basic value type arithmetic operations. In other words, there is no observable difference between the following:

```
checked {
  myType.CallSomeMethod();
}
```

and

```
myType.CallSomeMethod();
```

But lets say that there is an arithmetic operation, such as adding two integers. You would need to get the IL instructions for the method and check if the instructions around your method call are checked, and even that is far from bullet proof. You cannot tell if your custom operation is actually within the checked block, or just surrounded by checked blocks that it is not inside.

Even catching an exception will not work, since you cannot differentiate between these two cases:

```
checked {
  int a = (Some expression that overflows);
  myType.CallSomeMethod();
}
```

and

```
checked {
  int a = (Some expression that overflows);
}
myType.CallSomeMethod();
```

This is probably part of why the `Decimal` type does not attempt to detect `checked` vs `unchecked` and instead always throws `OverflowException`.