# Why does int.MinValue % -1 cause and OverflowException

Tags: c#, modulus, overflowexception

In 7.8.3. of the C# Specification regarding the Remainder operator it states the following:

> If the left operand is the smallest int or long value and the right
>   operand is -1, a System.OverflowException is thrown.

Therefore `int.MinValue % -1` would result in an OverflowException. I am trying to understand why?

Comment: Note that in Java, the result is `0` by specifications and in C the operation invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In two's complement arithmetic, data types have a range from (-2**n) to (2**n - 1) (where 'n' is 1 less than the number of bits in the data type).

For example, a 16-bit signed integer has a valid range from -32768 (-2**15) to 32767 (2**15 - 1).

-32768 / -1 = +32768 which exceeds the valid range for a 16-bit signed integer.

Comment: Mathematically `int.MinValue % -1` would be 0, or -1 (or possible 1).  This does not exceed the valid range for a 16-bit signed integer.

Comment: But it's typically computed by first dividing then finding the remainder.

Comment: Agree, but does the language specification require that order?

Comment: That I don't know. I'm a little surprised that C# doesn't handle it properly.

Comment: I suspect C# inherited C's specification: If `a/b` is not representable, then `a%b` is also undefined even if `a%b` is representable.

Comment: @chux I suspect they specified like this for performances reasons because on x86 and x64 the remainder can be obtained from the integer division processor instruction that computes in the same time the division and the remainder.

Comment: It makes sense to define the tautology `a == a/b + a%b`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31775042/why-does-the-c-sharp-specification-leave-int-minvalue-1-implementation-defi?lq=1 goes into details

Comment: @chux thank you for the answers. I was looking at this from a mathematical point of view and couldn't understand why C# treated it differently. Thank you for the link.

Comment: @keithmo your answer above rocks, thanks mate!

Comment: This is at best an incomplete answer. It discusses only why integer division might not work, while ignoring how and why that might impact the remainder operation. The question asked relates specifically to the remainder operation.